# Media Genre ID parser

Tags: java, beginner

The class below takes in a string of genre IDs deserialized from JSON and spits them back out in a format I can actually use. I'm definitely a beginner and would like to better myself, I feel like with this class specifically my lack of Java knowledge really shows.

Here is an example of the input the class is receiving, this of course varies by number of/order of variables so quite a few combinations are possible:

```
878,18,53
```

Here is the class itself.

```
public class GenreID {

private static final String id28 = "action";
private static final String id12 = "adventure";
private static final String id16 = "animated";
private static final String id35 = "comedy";
private static final String id80 = "crime";
private static final String id99 = "documentary";
private static final String id18 = "drama";
private static final String id10751 = "family";
private static final String id14 = "fantasy";
private static final String id36 = "history";
private static final String id27 = "horror";
private static final String id10402 = "musical";
private static final String id9648 = "mystery";
private static final String id10749 = "romance";
private static final String id878 = "sci-fi";
private static final String id53 = "thriller";
private static final String id10752 = "war";
private static final String id37 = "western";

public static String processGenre(String genreID) {

    StringBuilder included = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder excluded = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder includedExcluded = new StringBuilder();
    String includedPolished;

    excluded.append("\" data-excluded=\"");

    if(genreID.contains("28") || genreID.contains("10759")) {
        included.append(id28 + ", ");
    } else {
        excluded.append(id28 + " , ");
    }
    if (genreID.contains("12") || genreID.contains("10759")) {
        included.append(id12 + ", ");
    } else {
        excluded.append(id12 + " , ");
    }
    if (genreID.contains("16")) {
        included.append(id16 + ", ");
    } else {
        excluded.append(id16 + " , ");
    }
    if (genreID.contains("35")) {
        included.append(id35 + ", ");
    } else {
        excluded.append(id35 + " , ");
    }
    if (genreID.contains("80")) {
        included.append(id80 + ", ");
    } else {
        excluded.append(id80 + " , ");
    }
    if (genreID.contains("99")) {
        included.append(id99 + ", ");
    } else {
        excluded.append(id99 + " , ");
    }
    if (genreID.contains("18")) {
        included.append(id18 + ", ");
    } else {
        excluded.append(id18 + " , ");
    }
    if (genreID.contains("10751")) {
        included.append(id10751 + ", ");
    } else {
        excluded.append(id10751 + " , ");
    }
    if (genreID.contains("14") || genreID.contains("10765")) {
        included.append(id14 + ", ");
    } else {
        excluded.append(id14 + " , ");
    }
    if (genreID.contains("36")) {
        included.append(id36 + ", ");
    } else {
        excluded.append(id36 + " , ");
    }
    if (genreID.contains("27")) {
        included.append(id27 + ", ");
    } else {
        excluded.append(id27 + " , ");
    }
    if (genreID.contains("10402")) {
        included.append(id10402 + ", ");
    } else {
        excluded.append(id10402 + " , ");
    }
    if (genreID.contains("9648")) {
        included.append(id9648 + ", ");
    } else {
        excluded.append(id9648 + " , ");
    }
    if (genreID.contains("10749")) {
        included.append(id10749 + ", ");
    } else {
        excluded.append(id10749 + " , ");
    }
    if (genreID.contains("878") || genreID.contains("10765")) {
        included.append(id878 + ", ");
    } else {
        excluded.append(id878 + " , ");
    }
    if (genreID.contains("53")) {
        included.append(id53 + ", ");
    } else {
        excluded.append(id53 + " , ");
    }
    if (genreID.contains("10752") || genreID.contains("10768")) {
        included.append(id10752 + ", ");
    } else {
        excluded.append(id10752 + " , ");
    }
    if (genreID.contains("37")) {
        included.append(id37 + ", ");
    } else {
        excluded.append(id37 + " , ");
    }

    try {
        includedPolished = included.toString().substring(0,included.length() - 2);
    } catch (StringIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        includedPolished = null;
    }

    includedExcluded.append(includedPolished).append(excluded.toString().substring(0,excluded.length() - 2));

    return includedExcluded.toString();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a lot of repeated code here, so i've gone for an `enum` and loop approach to try to reduce this.

```
public enum Genre {

    action(new String[]{"28","10759"}),
    adventure(new String[]{"12", "10759"}),
    animated(new String[]{"16"}); //..

    private final String[] ids;

    Genre(String[] id) {
        this.ids = id;
    }

    public String[] getId() {
        return ids;
    }

}
```

The enum above contains a list of available id's which will trigger the genre being added to the `included` list in the `processGenre`. Other than that, it's just a simple enum.

```
 public String processGenre(String GenId){

    StringBuilder included = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder excluded = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder includedExcluded = new StringBuilder();
    String includedPolised;

    excluded.append("\" data-excluded=\"");


    List<String> splitGen = Arrays.asList(GenId.split(",")); //split the string by comma
    outer: for(Genre genre : Genre.values()){
        for(int i = 0; i < genre.getId().length; i++) {
            String id = genre.getId()[i];
            if (splitGen.contains(id)){
                included.append(genre.name()); //not "" + "", since string concatenation in a string builder is bad
                included.append(",");
                continue outer; //don't double count the genre if it has multiple id's
            }
        }
        excluded.append(genre.name()); //wasnt added to included, add to excluded
        excluded.append(",");

    }

    //do what you will with the results

    return includedExcluded.toString();
}
```

The above works by looping through the values of the enums, looking at the available string `ids`, and adding the genre, via the `.name()` method. Upon including the genre, the outer loop is continued to avoid double counting.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Nice, but a few pointers: when you use a variable in an enum, it should normally be final. To even protect it some more (as arrays are mutable), I suggest that you do *not* include a getter for the array, but basically move the check, whether a Genre matches a given split, to the enum as a method. This might return the string to append, so that you (1) eliminate the nested loop and (2) the break to outer.

Comment: In this example, you need to determine which Genres are included, and which are excluded. To move the check to the Genre, you would have to add the includes according to the check for each split, and then iterate over the included list to find which values are missing. That sounds like more code to me.

Comment: mtj does have a point about getting rid of the breaking to a label (which is always harder to understand at first sight what actually happens). I posted an alternative that get's arround this.

Comment: Wow, maybe it's because I'm so new to this but it seems like a lot of effort went into you reworking this for me, that's so awesome and so appreciated. The collaborated solution of yourself and Imus seems so elegant, I love it and am eager to deconstruct it down to each little aspect. Again, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Sam has a nice idea but it would be even better to provide a `hasIdIn(idList)` method on the enum instead of the getter for the list of IDs.

```
public enum Genre {

    action(new String[]{"28","10759"}),
    adventure(new String[]{"12", "10759"}),
    animated(new String[]{"16"}); //..

    private final String[] ids;

    Genre(String[] id) {
        this.ids = id;
    }

    public boolean hasIdIn(List<String> idList){
        for(String current : ids){
            if(idList.contains(current)){
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

That way we can simplify the nested for loops in the `processGenre` method:

```
List<String> splitGen = Arrays.asList(GenId.split(",")); //split the string by comma
for(Genre genre : Genre.values()){
    if(genre.hasIdIn(splitGen)){
        included.append(genre.name());
        included.append(",");
    } else {
        excluded.append(genre.name());
        excluded.append(",");
    }
}
```